# Unable to dereference pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, dereference

I am writing an implementation of the Haskell Maybe Monad in C++11.

However I got stuck when I tried to test the code. When I construt a value of the type with the pseudo constructor `Just` and then try to evaluate it with using the function `fromJust` (that should just "unpack" the value placed inside the Maybe) the program stops and eventually terminates silently.

So i tried to debug it; here is the output for the code of testMaybe.cpp:

```
c1
yeih2
value not null: 0xf16e70
```

I added a couple of print statements to evaluate where the program stops, and it seems to stop at the exact point where I dereference the pointer to return the value. (I have marked it in the code.)

At first I thought that the value in the maybe might have been deconstructed by the time i want to dereference the pointer, which, to my understanding, would result in undefined behaviour or termination. However, I was unable to find the place where that would have happened.

Can you please give me a hint on why this is happening?

testMaybe.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Maybe.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace Functional_Maybe;
int main() {
        Maybe<string> a{Maybe<string>::Just("hello") };
        if(!isNothing(a)) cout << "yeih2 " << fromJust(a) << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Maybe.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include<stdexcept>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace Functional_Maybe {

  template <typename T>
  class Maybe {
    const T* value;

    public:
          Maybe(T *v) : value { v } {}            //public for return in join
          const static Maybe<T> nothing;

          static Maybe<T> Just (const T &v) { cout << "c1" << endl; return Maybe<T> { new T(v) }; }

          T fromJust() const {
                  if (isNothing()) throw std::runtime_error("Tried to extract value from Nothing");
                  cout << "\nvalue not null: " << value << " " << *value << endl;
                                        //                        ^ stops here
                  return *value;
          }

          bool isNothing() const { return value==nullptr; }

          ~Maybe() { if (value != nullptr) delete value; }
  };

  template <typename T>
  bool isNothing(Maybe<T> val) {
    return val.isNothing();
  }

  template <typename T>
  T fromJust(Maybe<T> val) {
    return val.fromJust();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You class template `Maybe` owns resources (the dynamically allocated `T`), but does not follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1782465): the (implicitly defined) copy and move operations do shallow copies only, which leads to use-after-free and double-free problems. You should either implement proper copy and move operations (cosntructors and assignment operators) for your class, or use `std::unique_ptr<const T>` as the type of `value`, and remove your manual destructor (thereby following the preferred Rule of Zero).

Side note: have you looked into [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (or, in pre-C++17 versions, [`boost::optional`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html))? They seem to be doing something very similar (or even identical) to your proposed class, and you might want to use them instead (or use them internally in your class if that suits you better). They might even be more efficient, using small object optimisation to avoid dynamic memory allocation in some cases.

Comment: I have looked at C++17 optional; and the boost::optional;
However, it is a university project and we may not use boost or c++17

that's why I am implementing it myself...

Comment: @FabianSchneider OK, fair enough. You can at least take inspiration from them if you want to.